# How to group the array of object like this ? And remove duplicate?

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping, lodash

I am writing a small snippet of JS code which has an array:

```
[
 { title: 'title1', id: 1 },
 { title: 'title1', id: 2 },
 { title: 'title2', id: 3},
 { title: 'title2', id: 4}
]
```

I need something like this however:

```
"queried": {
    "title1": [1, 2],
    "title2": [3, 4],
 }
```

I am trying to do this with Lodash with `_.groupBy(array, "title")` but I get:

```
{ 
 title1:[
  { title: 'title1', id: 1 },
  { title: 'title1', id: 2 }
],
 title2:[
  { title: 'title2', id: 3 },
  { title: 'title2', id: 4 }
],
}
```

How to fix it please?

Comment: What is `id1` ... `id4`? In your first and last code piece, these are variables, in the middle one, they appear to be strings.

Comment: @connexp i edit post, its integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`_.mapValues()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mapValues) to iterate the groups, and [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map) to extracts the values of the ids:

```js
const lol = [{"title":"title1","id":1},{"title":"title1","id":2},{"title":"title2","id":3},{"title":"title2","id":4}];
  
const result = _.mapValues(
  _.groupBy(lol, 'title'),
  v => _.map(v, 'id')
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This also can be done without lodash via ES6 and `reduce` like so:

```js
var arr = [{ title: 'title1', id: 1 }, { title: 'title1', id: 2 }, { title: 'title2', id: 3 }, { title: 'title2', id: 4 } ]

const r = arr.reduce((r, {title, id}) => 
   (r[title] = [...r[title] || [], id], r), {})

console.log(r)
```

Comment: Great answer and thinking outside of the box - it also requires no 3rd party library like Lodash. +1